# How do I convert from NAD 83 State Plane Coordinates to Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: geography

I am trying to convert NAD 83 State Plane New York Long Island coordinates to Latitude/longitude.  Below is my code - what am I doing wrong?

```
LatitudeLongitude[GeoPosition[{172248, 1002321, 0}, "SPCS83NY04"]]
```

Comment: `Use GeodesyData["Datum"] for a list of available named datums.`

Comment: Cross posted here http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/159574;jsessionid=5877010A695FBB62406E1470F34CE70F.wlp2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
LatitudeLongitude @ GeoGridPosition[{172248, 1002321, 0}, "SPCS83NY04"]
(* {49.145, -75.732} *)
```

Comment: Good one. I delete my answer. +1

Comment: That does work!  What's weird is I used ArcGIS to calculate Lat/Long from the same set of coordinates, and I got 40.639439, -73.9349 instead.  Do you have any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: This is the projection info for the same datapoint in ArcGIS:                                                     Projected Coordinate System: NAD_1983_StatePlane_New_York_Long_Island_FIPS_3104_Feet
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting: 984250.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian: -74.00000000
Standard_Parallel_1: 40.66666667
Standard_Parallel_2: 41.03333333
Latitude_Of_Origin: 40.16666667
Linear Unit:  Foot_US

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:  Greenwich
Angular Unit:  Degree

Comment: @jackie Could be the units, feet instead of meters?  It's a big difference.

Comment: Thanks Michael!  That turned out to be the issue, and I got the same answer as the GIS application.  Do you understand why GeoGridPosition has to be used insted of GeoPosition - is it because State Plane is a projected coordinate system rather than a geographic one?  THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: @jackie No, I don't.  I would guess that `GeoPosition` is for positions (anywhere on Earth) based on a datum, and `GeoGridPosition` is for positions based on cartographic grids, which perhaps apply to only a limited region -- I think that's what you're suggesting.  My "expertise" with this problem is pretty much limited to being pretty good at finding things in the *Mathematica* documentation and knowing how *Mathematica* interfaces generally work.  GIS is not my field.  And you're welcome! :)